# VSTS: unable to access SSL certificate problem: (url) self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ssl, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have been deploying my application via VSTS for a while, and then suddenly I get this error:

unable to access SSL certificate problem: (url) self signed certificate in certificate chain.

Why has this suddenly happened and how do I fix it?

UPDATE: I notice that I have a new SSL certificate for the url that has been valid from a month ago, and after the last time I did a deployment.

Comment: You should add more information: SSL certificates are the norm for communication nowadays. When this happens, which task is running, to invoke which service, etc.

Comment: Which build task has this issue? Can you share the detailed logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the network team had changed the proxy firewall which caused this problem. To fix this they put the SSL certificate for the url in the certificate store. Now it works.